# What is the word that describes a person trying to sell stuff persistently?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, adjectives

I am trying to remember the word to describe a person trying to sell stuff persistently. I can't seem to figure it out.

-

It can be a verb, noun or adjective. Anything around "Selling stuff persistently".

Comment: At least in the U.S., the term _used-car salesman_ is sometimes used as an archetype of sorts to describe people who use pushy and often dishonest sales tactics – even when they are selling something other than automobiles.

Comment: Please clarify - are you looking for an adjective or a noun?  The tag shows "adjective" but the question seems to indicate "noun."

Comment: @JackRyan Sorry for the confusion. I actually just want to figure out a word that says "selling stuff persistently" it can be verb, noun or adjective depending the context you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call this person a **peddler** or a **hawker**.  Those terms make the sales person seem a little shady, **hustler** even more so.

Comment: I like hustler for a noun and I like solicit or tout for the verb. (:

Comment: Solicit or tout doesn't really convey anything that is pushy or negative.  Maybe haggle?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Haven't you seen those? You can happen upon them in just about every populated area.

Comment: However they might not be persistent :)

Answer (score 1):

***Pushy*** or ***pushful***
*marked by aggressive ambition and energy and initiative; [a pushful insurance agent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pushy)*

> A pushy door-to door salesman OR a pushy salesman

***Aggressive***

> This is one of the most common misconceptions about business today.
>   The reason that people think of salespeople [as being pushy and
>   aggressive](https://www.srpl.net/how-to-double-or-triple-your-sales-without-being-pushy-and-aggressive/) is because for the last 60 years, they have been pushy and
>   aggressive. Most sales people today still are.

***Insistent***
*making continual and persistent demands*

***pertinacious***
*continuing to believe something or [to do something in a very determined way](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pertinacious) [= tenacious]*

This is more formal, has a more positive spin, but really means the same as insistent, and persistent.

Comment: Pushful? I do not recall ever having heard or read that...

Comment: _Incessant_ comes in handy, too.

Comment: @mplungjan it's in The Free Dictionary, there's a link. I thought pushful sounded funny too, but maybe it's quite common in the US?

Comment: I think with -ful you tone down the subjectivity and colloquiality of -y.

Comment: It's not common, I've never ever heard it used either, but -ful can be added to many adjectives, it's your regular suffix.

Comment: @TaliaFord I use the word, pushy, four times. Pushful, once, apparently it is used, and I think it's helpful to be aware of these things.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I read ya. The you in 'in you tone down' was the proverbial you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to remember it too. I think it's

> High Pressure Salesman.

Found it on thesaurus.com along with

> hard sell.